# How do I efficiently query and sort a Custom Post Type via multiple custom fields with Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I am working on a wordpress site. I have a custom post type called "Members". Each member contains the following custom fields:

- Name
- Ship
- Rank (Captain, Lieutenant, or Seaman)

What I want to do is return all members of a given ship. I want to then organize the results by rank, with Captains in their own row (if they exist), then all Lieutenants in their own row (if they exist), followed by all Seamen.

Then, I want to repeat this for all subsequent ships.

I'm not sure if I should use multiple queries to do this, or if there's a clever way to handle the formatting via CSS.

What I'm currently doing is grabbing an array of all ships, grabbing an array of all ranks, and then looping through that with a new query per ship/rank:

```
<?php foreach( $allships as $ship ): ?>
    <div class="shipname">
        <?php echo $ship; ?> <!-- Ship Name -->
    </div>
    <?php foreach($ranks as $rank): ?>

    <div class=members id=<?php echo $ship . '-' . $rank;?>>
        
        <!-- new query per ship -->
        <?php
        // Custom Query to retrieve members
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'member',
                'posts_per_page' => -1, // Display all members
                'meta_query'    => array(
                    'relation'      => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'ship',
                        'value'     => $ship,
                        'compare'   => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'rank',
                        'value'     => $rank,
                        'compare'   => '='
                    )
                ),
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );
            $shipquery = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>

            <?php 
            // Check that we have query results.
            if ( $shipquery->have_posts() ) {
                // Start looping over the query results.
                while ( $shipquery->have_posts() ) {
                    $shipquery->the_post();
                    // Contents of the queried post results go here.
                    ?>
                    <div class=member>
                        <?php $image = get_field('photo');
                            if( !empty( $image ) ): ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
                        <?php
                        if ($rank == 'firstmate' || $rank =='secondmate')
                          echo "<h2>" . $rank . "</h2>"
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            // Restore original post data.
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <hr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: How many entities are we talking about, a couple, dozens, hundreds, thousands? It might be easiest to just grab them all and then sort and filter in PHP.

Comment: Probably 100 - 200. What I've done now is grab the array of ships, and then iterate through that with a new query per ship.

I'm going to update the question.

Comment: Can you describe how you'd filter a single query using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following replacement WP_Query, that will, for a given "ship", sort by "rank" first and after by "name":

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'member',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Display all members
    'meta_query'     => array( 
        'relation'    => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'ship',
            'value'   => $ship,
        ),
        'rank_clause' => array(
            'key'     => 'rank',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'name_clause' => array(
            'key'     => 'name',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'rank_clause' => 'ASC',
        'name_clause' => 'ASC',
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks, Loic. That query does indeed work and return results in the order specified. However, with all the posts in a single query like this, I'm finding it difficult to format the results the way I want. Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve the formatting I asked about in my initial question when using the query this way? There is a live demo at http://sealords.convoke.info/roster/